# Make a paragraph visible through parent object

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a small assignment and therefore not allowed to use javascript. Only html and css. I made a simple gallery with products and when I hover over them I'd like the small paragraph to become visible. Is there a way to 'call' the paragraph from the .product-container? I tried adding a + p but that doesn't seem to work. I also don't want to make a specific class for every div so ideally only the corresponding products paragraph is visible when hovering and not all of them. Hope you understand what I mean, I don't know the exact phrases to use since I'm very new.

```css
#navbarDog {
    background-color: #F5EFE6;
}

#logo {
    height: 100px;
}
body{
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: bold;
    size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1, 5;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: font-size 0.4s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.header-products {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #E8DFCA;
    padding: 50px;
}

main {
    background-color: #AEBDCA;
}

.gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery img {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: relative;
}
.product-container p{
    visibility: hidden;
}
/* .gallery img:hover {
    z-index: 9;
    transform: scale(1.3);
    transition: transform ease 0.5s;
} */
.product-container:hover {
    z-index: 9;
    transform: scale(1.3);
    transition: transform ease 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .gallery {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

#footer {
    background-color: #7895B2;
    padding: 4%;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-icon {
    color: #fe0707;
    margin: 20px 10px;

    text-decoration: none;

}

/* Adds color to hovering state (element.class.action in this order) */
a.footer-icon:hover {
    color: #41678e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Products</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b88143462d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="navbarDog">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="" id="logo"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="news.html">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <form class="d-flex ms-auto">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="header-products">
        <h1>Products</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="product-container">
                <img src="../img/tshirt-beighe.jpg" alt="">
                <p>A stylish t-shirt made of 100% cotton. 450SEK</p>
            </div>
            <img src="../img/tshirt-blue.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="../img/tshirt-gray.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="../img/tshirt-white.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="../img/tshirt-yellow.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="footer-icon fa-brands fa-instagram"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="footer-icon fa-brands fa-facebook"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="footer-icon fa-brands fa-twitter"></a>
        <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/" class="footer-icon fa-brands fa-snapchat"></a>

        <p>© Copyright OnlyDogs</p>
    </footer>




</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Using general sibling selector. Doesn't matter what order.

```css
img:hover ~ .product-container p {
 visibility: visible
}
```

If that fails:
Wrap your image in a link tag and then do this.

```css
a:hover img ~ .product-container p {
 visibility: visible
}
```

Comment: `image:hover` is invalid. I think it should be either `img:hover` or `.image:hover`.

Comment: 'doesn't matter what order' - yes it does. you are showing hover on image (I assume you mean img) where the img is parent of product-container, but it's the other way round. Your second option makes no sense. Where are these anchor tags coming from in relation to the bunch of images that are to be shown? There don't seem to be any a elements that are siblings of .product-container elements.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, when you hover the img, you want to affect the sibling (doesnt matter if the sibling is before the img or after) and that sibling child - ie the p tag. I think you are confusing ~ with >. > is a direct child. As for the link (I said above - wrap your images in links)

Comment: If the sibling is before the img then a ~ won't work as It does not select any old sibling, the sibling has to come after. That is one of the pains when having a label and input combination. See developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors which states - " This means that the second element follows the first". MDN gives a fuller description.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the hover on the parent element:

```css
.product-container p {
  display: none;
}
.product-container:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
  <p>A stylish t-shirt made of 100% cotton. 450SEK</p>
</div>
```